# Fixed in radio button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

Shown in the image. I click on buy button after clicking on sell button, another div its disable by radio button. How can I create radio button group in laravel? How can I select both buy and sell?

[image]

```html
<div class="form-group col-sm-5">
            {{ Form::radio('is_action', 1) }} Buy
            {{ Form::radio('is_action', 0) }} Sell
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
            {{ Form::radio('is_action', 1) }} Buy
            {{ Form::radio('is_action', 0) }} Sell
        </div>
```

Comment: Snippet compiles html template only.

Comment: Give different name to both section. For example, for first section give name like `name="first_selection_section"` and for second, give name like: `name="second_selection_section"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have several options with the same name you can only select one radio button.

```
    <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
        {{ Form::radio('is_action', 1) }} Buy
        {{ Form::radio('is_action', 0) }} Sell  
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
        {{ Form::radio('is_action', 1) }} Buy
        {{ Form::radio('is_action', 0) }} Sell
    </div>
```

here you can only select one from these four radio buttons.If you want more to select then add different names like below;

```
    <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
        {{ Form::radio('is_action_1', 1) }} Buy
        {{ Form::radio('is_action_2', 0) }} Sell  
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
        {{ Form::radio('is_action_3', 1) }} Buy
        {{ Form::radio('is_action_4', 0) }} Sell
    </div>
```

for more details refer to http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/168/creating-a-radio-button-input-field